# Сортировка столбцов матрицы

Tags: c++

Задание звучит так:

*Характеристикою стовпця матриці назвемо суму його від’ємних непарних елементів. Переставляючи стовпці матриці, розташувати їх відповідно до спадання характеристик.*

То есть, рассмотрим пример на вот такой матрице:

**-3 -5  1  0**

**1 -3 -1  0**

**-2  3  0  0**

По заданию мы должны из каждого столбца узнать сумму его отрицательных нечетных элементов.

Из первого столбца мы достаем только **-3**, из второго сумму **-3** и **-5**, то есть **-8**, из третьего берем **-1**, а в четвертом у нас **0**.

Из этих сумм у нас строится вот такой масивчик:

**-3 -8 -1 0**

и сортируется по убыванию:

**0 -1 -3 -8**

Как мне теперь доработать код в 130 строке, чтобы по этому массиву у меня сортировались столбцы основного массива? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
float Scaner();

struct Matrix {
    int rows, columns;
    int **ptr;
};

void inputMatrixRandom(Matrix matrix);
void inputMatrixKeyboard(Matrix matrix);
void sortMatrix(Matrix matrix);
void outputMatrix(Matrix matrix);
void removeMasiv(Matrix matrix);
Matrix vidileniePamiati(int rows, int columns);

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    char v;

    int rows, columns;

    cout << "Введите кол-во строк матрицы:\n";
    cout << " > ";
    rows = (int)Scaner();

    cout << "Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы:\n";
    cout << " > ";
    columns = (int)Scaner();

    Matrix t = vidileniePamiati(rows, columns);

    do {
        cout << "\nВыберите действие:" << endl;
        cout << " 1 - Заполнение матрицы рандомными числами" << endl;
        cout << " 2 - Заполнение матрицы с клавиатуры" << endl;
        cout << " 3 - Выполнение задания" << endl;
        cout << " 4 - Вывод матрицы на консоль" << endl;
        cout << " 0 - Выход" << endl;
        cout << "  > ";

        v = _getche();

        switch (v) {
        case '1':
            inputMatrixRandom(t);
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "\n\nЗаполните массив:\n";
            inputMatrixKeyboard(t);
            break;
        case '3':
            sortMatrix(t);
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << "\n\nПостроенная матрица:\n";
            outputMatrix(t);
            break;
        case '0':
            removeMasiv(t);
            break;
        default:
            cout << " [ERROR] Вы ввели некорректное значение." << endl;
        } // закрывающая switch
    } while (v != '0');
    return 0;
}

void inputMatrixRandom(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++)
            matrix.ptr[i][j] = rand() % 100;
}

void inputMatrixKeyboard(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++)
            cin >> matrix.ptr[i][j];
    }
}

void outputMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
            cout << matrix.ptr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void sortMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    int *chislo = new int[matrix.columns];
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
        chislo[j] = 0;
    }

    cout << "\n\nПроверка на подходимость числа:" << endl;

    // Проверка на подходимость и занесение подходящих чисел в массив chislo
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
            if (matrix.ptr[i][j] % 2 == -1) {
                cout << " +"; // отладочный вывод
                chislo[j] += matrix.ptr[i][j];
            }
            else {
                cout << " -"; // отладочный вывод
                chislo[j] += 0;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i < matrix.columns; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns - i; j++) {
            if (chislo[j] < chislo[j + 1]) {
                int temp = chislo[j];
                chislo[j] = chislo[j + 1];
                chislo[j + 1] = temp;

                for () {

                }

            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Отсортированные характеристики:" << endl;

    // Проверял такой массив:
    // -3 -5  1  0
    //  1 -3 -1  0
    // -2  3  0  0

    // Проверка корректного занесения подходящих чисел со столбцов матрицы в одномерный массив chislo
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
        cout << chislo[j] << " ";  // отладочный вывод 
    }                                            
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    cout << "Отсортированная матрица:" << endl;
    outputMatrix(matrix);
}

void removeMasiv(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
            delete[] matrix.ptr[j];
            delete[] matrix.ptr[i];
        }
    }
    delete[] matrix.ptr;
}

Matrix vidileniePamiati(int rows, int columns) {
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.rows = rows;
    matrix.columns = columns;
    matrix.ptr = new int*[matrix.rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++)
        matrix.ptr[i] = new int[matrix.columns];
    return matrix;
}

float Scaner() {
    bool good = true;
    float a;
    do {
        cin >> a;
        if (!(cin.good())) {
            good = false;
            cout << " [ERROR] Некорректное значение, повторите попытку:" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << " > ";
        }
        else
            good = true;
    } while (!good);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: У вас ошибки в рассуждениях: `По заданию мы должны из каждого столбца узнать сумму его отрицательных нечетных элементов.
Из первого столбца мы достаем только -3, из второго сумму -3 и -5, то есть -8, из третьего берем -1, а в четвертом у нас 0.` Первый столбец -2; -3; Второй -5; Третий; Четвёртый ; => -5 ; -5; 0; 0; => 0; 0; -5; -5. Не понятно что делать со столбцами, у которых сумма отрицательных нечётных элементов одинакова

Comment: ну либо под нечётными элементами имелись в виду нечётные числа, а не их порядковые номера в столбце. Не понятно

Comment: @vegorov Представим, что все столбцы будут с разной суммой элементов. Под нечётными элементами имелись в виду действительно нечётные числа, а не их порядковые номера. В первом столбце нам подходит только -3, потому что -2 оно отрицательное, но чётное.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Подход правильный. Осталось только поменять столбцы **и** их характеристики. Вспоминайте метод сортировки самый простой основываясь на характеристики столбов.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < matrix.columns; ++i) {
      size_t smallest_stolb = matrix.columns - i ;
      // находим самый маленькую характеристику столбов
      for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns - i; j++)
        if (chislo[j] < chislo[smallest_stolb])
          smallest_stolb = j ;       
      // столбы меняем, и их характеристику
      for (int j = 0; j < matrix.rows; j++) {
        int tmp = matrix.ptr[j][matrix.columns - i];
        matrix.ptr[j][matrix.columns - i] = matrix.ptr[j][smallest_stolb];
        matrix.ptr[j][smallest_stolb] = tmp ; }
      { int temp = chislo[matrix.columns - i];
        chislo[matrix.columns - i] = chislo[smallest_stolb];
        chislo[smallest_stolb] = temp; } }
```

Ещё ошибка удаления матрицы:

```
void removeMasiv(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
        /*for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
            delete[] matrix.ptr[j];*/
            delete[] matrix.ptr[i];
        //}
    }
    delete[] matrix.ptr; }
```

Comment: Эх, мне бы готовую функцию sortMatrix.

Comment: @MrInno Исправил и проверил. У меня всё пашет.

Comment: Прекрасно, спасибо большое!